# Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'function'

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

i have been writing test case for my dashboard module but its showing error in this test case file but the front end is working fine:
this is the code:
Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'function'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { employees } = useSelector((state) => state.employees);
  const { results } = useSelector((state) => state.results);
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(1);
  const [succesEmplo, setSuccessEmplo] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTotalEmployees(""));
    dispatch(getTotalRes());
  }, [currentId]);
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    var successEmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        if (
          employees[i]._id === results[j].empId &&
          !successEmp.includes(employees[i])
        ) {
          successEmp.push(employees[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    setSuccessEmplo(successEmp);
  }, [employees, results]);
  const showSidebar = () => {
    setSidebar(!sidebar);
  };
```

this is my total emp function:

```
export const getTotalEmployees = (category) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchTotalEmployees(category);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOTAL, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

and gettotalres function:

```
export const getTotalRes = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchTotalRes();
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOTAL_RES, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

test case code:
import React from 'react';

```
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react';
import Dashboard from '../Pages/dashboard/Dashboard';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';
const setup = () => {
  const store = createStore(() => ({
    employees: {
      employees: [
        {
          _id: '1',
          username: 'Employee 1',
          createdAt: new Date().toJSON(),
        },
        {
          _id: '2',
          username: 'Employee 2',
          createdAt: '2022-12-12T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
      ],
    },
    results: {
      results: [
        {
          empId: '1',
          result: 'pass',
        },
      ],
    },
  }));
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const utils = render(
    
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
      <Dashboard />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );

  return {
    ...utils,
    store,
  };
};

test('/useEffect is called on mount and when currentId changes', () => {
  const useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect');
  setup();
  expect(useEffect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  React.useEffect.mockRestore();
});

test('getTotalEmployees and getTotalRes actions are dispatched', () => {
  const { store } = setup();
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
    { type: 'GET_TOTAL_EMPLOYEES', payload: '' },
    { type: 'GET_TOTAL_RES' },
  ]);
});
```

Comment: What are the `getTotalEmployees` and `getTotalRes` functions? If they return a function, then that's then being passed into `dispatch`, which would cause the error

Comment: editted question please go through it

Comment: I do not see any unit test code. Could you add the failing test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't test the useEffect is called.
you need to test what is happening in the useEffect.
You have 2 options:

- mock the dispatch and check that it is called with the right arguments.
- test the side effects if there is some. For example, is calling dispatch(getTotalEmployees) changes anything in your component? If yes you can check that whatever effect happen it is matching your expectation